# Why is texture distorting at the sides? How to fix it?

Tags: texturing

I have used a basic plane and cloth simulator. Solidify and subsurf modifiers applied after. I'm trying to get the lines to be straight vertically and horizontally but can't figure out what has went wrong or how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I'm still in early learning stages of blender[image: 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HW1K.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using object coords. If you watch it right from above it will look okay. But since the edges of the blanket are not flat and have some verticality, X axis projects onto it and you see the distortion
[image]

[image]

The solution I think is to unwrap the mesh and use UV coordinates:

[image: Using UV coords]

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: @BuildInteriors If this answer is indeed useful for you, make sure to upvote and accept it. That's how thanking for help is done on SE.